# Кодировка русского содержания в html-коде

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

Помогите решить вопрос с кодировкой русского текста в коде программ SublimeText3, NotePad или Dreamweaver. Он отображается цифрами и символами &#.

Попытка изменить через опцию "Изменить -> Свойства страницы" не дает результата.

В секции хэд указываю кодировку явно (utf-8). В визуальном режиме или в браузере русский текст отображается корректно. Но в режиме просмотра кода вместо русских символов - цифры и символы &#.

Сама страница в юникоде (utf-8). Во всяком случае, это указано в свойствах страницы.

Comment: А кодировка самого файла какая?

Comment: Юникод (UTF-8) (это то, что в свойствах страницы)

Comment: А не копировали вы случайно в ваш файл с utf-8 кириллические символы из файла с windows cp 1251?

Comment: А в самом UTF-8 уже зашито `&#xxxx;`?  Если да - то как вариант  Search + Replace ручками в блокноте. Возможно этот вариант будет вам проще других.

Comment: Если да, то советую взять содержимое файла, все символы привести к utf-8

Comment: Можно некрасивые символы сунуть сюда скопом и перекодировать http://www.online-decoder.com/ru

Comment: Там я была. Это крайне неудобно. Ищу более разумное решение